# Zebra striping after jQuery remove()

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery to zebra-stripe my table because it works for ie8.

`$('table.data tr:nth-child(odd)').css('background-color', '#ececec');`

Problem is, I have a button that allows you to remove a row.

`$(this).parents('tr').remove();`

Which throws off the zebra striping. So I've tried:

```
$(this).parents('tr').remove();
$('table.data tr:nth-child(odd)').css('background-color', '#ececec');
$('table.data tr:nth-child(even)').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

And

```
$(this).parents('tr').remove();
$('table.data tr').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
$('table.data tr:nth-child(odd)').css('background-color', '#ececec');
```

Neither of which work. `.remove()` doesn't have a callback function or I'd put the zebra striping in it. Any ideas?

Edit - the code above works, but there was a css conflict. (See answer below). The conflict however doesn't set the background color. So, I would still like to know why the rule causes a conflict.

Comment: Your first example works for me: [Full Screen](http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/cN8Hb/1/embedded/result/) + [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/cN8Hb/1/light/)

Comment: why not simply:`$('table.data tr:odd').css('background-color', '#ececec');
$('table.data tr:even').css('background-color', '#ffffff');` removing nth-child?

Comment: That actually fixed the problem I stated in my answer below... thanks! Reason I ended up with the selector I did is because during testing with IE8 some selectors I tried didn't work, and I ended up with that one.

Answer (score 1):

`.remove` doesn't need a callback as it is synchronous. I'd suggest moving away from `.css`and using a class, that way you can simply remove the class, then add it back to the odd rows.

to do the initial striping:

```
$('table.data tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

and then on remove:

```
$(this).parents('tr').remove();
$('table.data tr').removeClass('odd').filter(':nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

Comment: why does the original fail?

Comment: @JanDvorak My guess would be a css conflict, but i can't confirm that without html/css. His original code will work with the right html/css. I guess this really should be a comment, but there's quite a bit of code here, it wouldn't be very readable as a comment.

Comment: I don't know... sorry to trouble everyone. I don't have any css conflicts, I'll have to keep troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targetting fairly modern browser (IE 9+), you can use CSS3 stylesheets to handle all of this.

style.css:

```
table.data tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: #ececec;
}
table.data tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

No javascript needed; these rules are applied by the browser and re-applied automatically if the DOM changes.

Comment: *"I use jQuery to zebra-stripe my table because it works for ie8."* though i agree, should use CSS3 and only degrade to js for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: @KevinB heh, yeah maybe I should read the first line of the question. Nevertheless, this might prove useful to others who come to this question.

Comment: @KevinB If you're already including the js to zebra stripe, why would you waste the extra lines of css to do the same?

Comment: @inorganik That can go the other way too. If you're alraedy including the css to zebra stripe, why would you waste the extra lines of js to do the same? (hint: you can include css/js for IE8 specifically with conditional comments)

Comment: Basically, why should the modern browsers suffer to add support for the older browser when said support can be added without affecting the modern browsers.

Comment: @KevinB I'm of the school of thought that if 1 way works for all browsers, use that way. How are modern browsers suffering? There can't possibly be a performance cost zebra-striping with js. Using CSS and js just requires more lines of unnecessary code.

Comment: You are correct, it's an optimization that isn't necessarily needed. The difference in this case will be small, as long as your row count is also small.

Comment: Here's an out-of-the-box idea, Why not have your rows have a set height and use a repeating background image on your table to simulate zebra stripes? Then you won't need to modify classes or css at all for zebra striping, even when you remove a row, as long as you can keep the striping in line with the rows.

Comment: I've used that approach. Problem is, the size of the site, and the variance of data, it's impossible to control row height. Thanks for your help on this. Take a look at my answer below- poses another question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The code in my question works, but there was a css conflict. Oddly though, the css rule that was causing the conflict doesn't set `background-color`

```
table.headerShadow tr:nth-child(2) {
    background-image:url(../_images/faux-shadow.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Removing the rule fixes the problem. Odd, eh? Why would that rule cause a conflict?

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/W7yZC/2/

Comment: I don't quite understand why that causes the issue, but, it's relatively easy to fix. Add a thead and tbody to your table, and target that css rule at the thead only. http://jsfiddle.net/W7yZC/4/ It would also make sense at that point to target the js at only the tbody.